# Earth Science questions at Astronomy

Tags: support

How soon will we be able to migrate Earth Science questions from Astronomy?

We have one in particular awaiting migration, but probably some other good ones that were closed as off topic.

[Why is there a daily inequality for low tides?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/why-is-there-a-daily-inequality-for-low-tides)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't really migrate questions to beta sites. As Anna (a former Stack Exchange Community Manager, now dev) [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/237685):

> Migrating to beta sites isn't something we encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional migration doesn't hurt much.

Another general rule [is don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/237685). Only migrate questions that are truly exemplary. That question looks to be a good question, and seems to be on-topic here, but given we've only been in beta for all of a few hours... it's much too soon.

It would probably be best to bring this up sometime after we go into public beta, and probably check in chat to see if people think it's a good fit for this site. If there are more good questions like that, do the same thing! But first make sure it's a *very* high quality question. Also, please note: there is a 60 day limit on when a question can be migrated. If it's older than 60 days, it can't be migrated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for public beta and probably even until Earth Science has moderators. It will be easier to manage the success of migrations at that point.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that this is a good question to migrate when we're ready - although the answers might cover quite a lot of the same ground as those to http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/316/what-influences-tide-height-the-most-can-i-guess-the-height-by-looking-on-a-glo